# abstract method foo(E) in wtf.is.going.on cannot be accessed directly super.foo(e) compiling with ANT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, generics, ant

```
abstract method foo(E) in wtf.is.going.on cannot be accessed directly super.foo(e)
```

I get that error when compiling my project with `ANT` using the auto generated `ANT` build file from `ANDROID`.

When i compile the same project in `ECLIPSE`, i do not get any issues. What is happening?

---

Here is what is going on:

```
package wtf.is.going.on;
public interface DAOMutator<E> {

    public void foo(E e);

}
```

---

```
package wtf.is.going.on;
public class DAOBImpl<E extends DAO> implements DAOMutator<E> {

    @Override
    public void foo(DAO dao) {
        //do some stuff
    }

}
```

---

```
package wtf.is.going.on.more;
public class VMBImpl <E extends someDao> extends DAOBImpl<E> {

    @Override
    public void foo(E e) {
    super.foo(e); // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    }

}
```

---

Exact error output:

```
[javac] MYPATH\src\wtf\is\going\on\more\VMBImpl.java:6: abstract method foo(E) in wtf.is.going.on.DAOMutator cannot be accessed directly
[javac]             super.foo(e);
```

Comment: My `public interface DAOMutator<E>` also needed to be changed to `public interface DAOMutator<E extends DAO>`. This fixed the other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch

```
public void foo(DAO dao)
```

in DAOBImpl to

```
public void foo(E dao)
```

Does it work properly?

Comment: Yes it did. It caused other issues, but at least that works now. Thanks